# Implement live555 DeviceSource to receive frame from ffmpeg encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, live555

I am making a application for streaming webcam. I would like to use OpenCV to capture camera, ffmpeg as encoder and live555 as server. I know I must implement DeviceSource.cpp in live555 to encapsulate the encoder to receive frame from ffmpeg. However, there seems to be no example of how to do this. So can anyone provide me some tutorial or example about implementing DeviceSource. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

[DeviceSource.cpp](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/doxygen/html/DeviceSource_8cpp-source.html) **is** an example of implementing a Live555 FramedSource that uses live data. Take a look at the DeviceSource.cpp file and read the comments. In particular, pay attention to the following lines in `deliverFrame()`:

```
u_int8_t* newFrameDataStart = (u_int8_t*)0xDEADBEEF; //%%% TO BE WRITTEN %%%
unsigned newFrameSize = 0; //%%% TO BE WRITTEN %%%
```

This is where you set your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of what you are after here:

https://www.imc-store.com.au/Articles.asp?ID=278

It is a c++ VS2010 project showing how to encode a raw RGB frame using FFMPEG, and then sending that discrete frame onto Live555 to be streamed.

The VS2010 project includes all the library and include files so it should simply be a case of unzipping, running the .sln file in VS2010, compile and run!

Also the VLC source code implements both FFMPEG and Live555, you could take a look at their code for some extra pointers!

Good luck!